# Laravel Excel queued export isn't creating jobs

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to get queued exports to work with the Laravel Excel package, but can't figure out what I'm missing.  I followed the docs on [how to queue exports](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html), but when I test it the export completes after the first batch is exported, so after the first 1000 rows.  I setup my application to use the [database driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#driver-prerequisites) in .env and generated/ran the migrations.

I'm using Laravel 5.8, Laravel Excel 3.1, PHP 7.2, Postgresql 10.  Here's a basic version of what I have so far:

Controller

```
public function export(Request $request){
    $name = 'test.csv';
    (new ExcelExport($client, $year))->queue('public/exports/' . $name)->chain([
        new NotifyUserOfExport($request->user(), $name),
    ]);

    return back()->with('message', 'This export will take some time. You will receive an email when it is ready to download.');
}
```

Export Class

```
class ExcelExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, WithMapping, WithStrictNullComparison
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($client, $year)
    {
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $query = $this->getQuery();

        return $query;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        //...
    }

    public function map($row): array
    {
        //....
    }

    private function getQuery()
    {
        return \DB::table('mytable')
                  ->where('year', $this->year)
                  ->where('client', $this->client)
                  ->orderBy('created_at')
                  ->groupBy('column');
    }
```

My queue.php

```
return [
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),
    'connections' => [
        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs', // also tried 'myschema.jobs'
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
        //.....
    ],
```

My .env

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

I don't think there's any other code that's relevant. I get the notification that's supposed to send after all the jobs are finished, but like I mentioned earlier, it's sent after the first batch is completed.  There are no jobs inserted into the jobs table in the database either, so there's the problem.  I just can't figure out what I'm missing.

I should mention that I don't want to use the [Implicit Export queueing](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html#implicit-export-queueing), since this same export is used in another part of the application that only requires a few rows to be exported, so I don't need to queue it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that because my query had a groupBy clause, I needed to implement [a custom query size](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html#custom-query-size) on the export class.  I don't understand why that's an issue, but after I added that, the jobs were added to the queue and processed fine.  So I added:

```
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomQuerySize;

    class ExcelExport implements ...., WithCustomQuerySize

    //......

    public function querySize(): int
    {
        $query = //......

        $size = $query->count();
        return $size;
    }
```

I hope this helps someone so they don't have to go through the headache I did.

Answer (score 0):

Queued exportables are processed in chunks; each chunk being a job pushed to the queue by the QueuedWriter. In case of exportables that implement the FromQuery concern, the number of jobs is calculated by dividing the $query->count() by the chunk size.

#When to use

Depending on the implementation of the query() method (e.g. when using a groupBy clause), the calculation mentioned before might not be correct.

If this is the case, you should use the WithCustomQuerySize concern to provide a custom calculation of the query size.

Read more about here https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html#when-to-use